# update a file content in SharePoint document library with REST - javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I want to update a file in SharePoint document library with the following code. As descriptions in:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx#bk_FileRequestExamples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_FileRequestExamples)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553(v=office.15).aspx#Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553%28v=office.15%29.aspx#Files)

The executeAsync returns successful but the file isn’t update!
Can anybody help!?

```
var spUrl = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + itemUrl + "')/$value?@target='" + hostWebUrl + "'";
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl);
    executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url: spUrl,
        type: "POST",
        body: "Here is the new Body",
        headers: {
            "X-HTTP-Method": "PUT",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: readContents,
        error: errorHandler,
        state: "Update"
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the add method it gives me the error message!!!!

So I find out I should use "method" instead of "type" when I update.

Answer (score 1):

Based on MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735924.aspx#properties
you have to use:
url, method, headers, success and error

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem. changing

```
body: "Here is the new Body",
```

to

```
data: "Here is the new Body",
```

solved the issue for me